# How to use AES encryption twice using CryptoJS AES

Tags: javascript, aes, cryptojs

i try to encrypt twice using cryptojs but its nothing return how i do that this is my code

```
var defaultKey = "Part of the journy is the end. Whatever it takes";
var userKey = 'in this whole universe iron man is the best superhero';
var encryptMsg ='';

encryptMsg = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(msg, defaultKey);
alert(encryptMsg);
encryptMsg = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(encryptMsg , userKey );
alert(encryptMsg);
```

first alert show encrypted text but seconf alert not display anything

Answer (score 0):

oooyeh i found a solution i dont know this is right way but this thing work for me

```
var defaultKey = "Part of the journy is the end. Whatever it takes";
var userKey = 'in this whole universe iron man is the best superhero';
var encryptMsg ='';

encryptMsg = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(msg, defaultKey);
alert(encryptMsg);
encryptMsg = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(String(encryptMsg) , userKey );
alert(encryptMsg);
```

i use String()